# Laravel Регистрация пользователя после неудачной авторизации

Tags: php, laravel, laravel5, auth, laravel-5.6

В Laravel 5.6 необходимо сделать следующие.

Есть форма авторизации - обрабатывает LoginController, в моем случае я поменяла email на name, и остался password.

Если такой пользователь есть с таким паролем, то авторизую его, а если пользователя нет с таким именем и паролем, то нужно зарегистрировать с данными которые были введены.

Вот class LoginController

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;


class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/';
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    protected function redirectTo()
    {
        return '/';
    }

    public function username() {
        return 'name';
    }

    /**
     * Handle a failed authorization attempt.
     *
     * @return void
     *
     * @throws \Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException
     */


    protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
    {
        // Что то нужно сделать чтоб зарегить пользователя

    }
```

Я думала переопределить функцию sendFailedLoginResponse чтоб в этот момент регистрировать пользователя. Запустить как то RegisterController и передать данные с POST запроса.

Подскажите как нужно реализовать данную идею?

Comment: Просто создайте клиента и авторизуйте

Comment: не надо котнролер туда в контроллер пихать

Comment: Я так понимаю по сути скопировать функцию register ?

Comment: `public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

        event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

        $this->guard()->login($user);

        return $this->registered($request, $user)
                        ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }`

Answer (score 0):

нет просто типа

```
$user = new User();
$user->name = 'test';
$user->email = 'test';
$user->password = md5('test');
$user->save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно просто создать метод login и в нем:

```
$user = User::firstOrCreate([
    'name' => $request->name
], [
    'name' => $request->name,
    'password' => Hash::make($request->password)
]);

// или то что ниже
if ($user && Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
    auth()->loginUsingId($user->id);
}
```

Код ищет пользователя по имени, если не находит, то создает с полями в втором массиве. И не зависимо нашло ли пользователя или он был зарегистрирован – если совпадает пароль, то пользователь аутентифицируется по id. Попробуйте, код не проверял.

Впринципе можно и это условие вместо того использовать:

```
if (auth()->attempt(['name' => $request->name, 'password' => $request->password])) {
    // успешно
}
```

А вообще логичней не делать так как Вы хотите, что если пользователь просто не помнит учетных данных, а вы ему новый аккаунт регистрируете?

Answer (score 0):

Все ответы помогли найти решение. Сделала вот так:

```
public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required|string',
            'password' => 'required|string'
        ]);
        $user = User::firstOrCreate([
            'name' => $request->name
        ], [
            'name' => $request->name,
            'password' => Hash::make($request->password)
        ]);

        if ($user && Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
            auth()->loginUsingId($user->id);
            return redirect()->intended('/');
        } else {
            throw ValidationException::withMessages([
                $this->username() => [trans('auth.failed')],
            ]);
        }
    }
```